# Symfony2 DataTransfomer that depends on second value?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a model where an Appointment object has a OneToMany relationship with a Reminder object. I want to embed a collection of Reminder forms in an Appointment form. The Appointment object has a property Appointment.Date. The Reminder object also has a property Reminder.Date.

I made a custom type called "IntervalType", consisting of a "number" dropdown and a "unit" dropdown to use for the Reminder.Date input. The idea is that the user selects a number and a unit ("1 hour", "2 days", etc.).

I then need to transform "2 days" into a DateTime value for Reminder.Date that is 2 days earlier than the Appointment.Date. I am trying to figure out how to do this with a custom DataTransformer called "IntervalToDateTransformer". I can add the data transformer to the Reminder form, or the IntervalType input, etc., but how do I make the transformer aware of what the Reminder's parent Appointment.Date is?

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought it was not possible because of some research I had done before on this issue. I decided to try it and I got it to work. Basically I created a custom form type that had two fields issue and option. Then I managed to get those two valuse in the data transform class where they can be used for the transformation. Here are the files.

```
Note that the 'option' field is not used, but I did verify 
it was accessible from the data transformer.

Also, I could not manage to render the validation messages declared 
on the data transform class when transformation fails. I stopped 
there, but if you manage to do it let me know.
```

First FormType

```
class IssueSelectorType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $om;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $om
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('number', 'text', array(
                // 'mapped' => false
        ));
        $builder->add('option', 'choice', array(
                // 'mapped' => false
        ));

          $transformer = new IssueToNumberTransformer($this->om);
          $builder->addViewTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'invalid_message' => 'The selected issue does not exist',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'issue_selector';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'field';
    }

}
```

Data transformer class:

```
class IssueToNumberTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $om;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $om
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (issue) to a array .
     *
     * @param  Issue|null $issue
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform($issue)
    {
        if (null === $issue)
        {

            return array(
                'number' => 0,
                'option' => 0
                    );
        }

        return array(
            'number' => $issue->id,
            'option' => 0
        );
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a array  to an object (issue).
     *
     * @param  array $value
     * @return Issue|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (issue) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_array($value))
        {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'array');
        }
        $number = $value['number'] ;
        $option = $value['option'] ;

        $issue = $this->om
                ->getRepository('AcmeTransformerBundle:Issue')
                ->findOneBy(array('id' => $number))
        ;

        if (null === $issue)
        {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                            'An issue with number "%s" does not exist!', $number
            ));
        }

        return $issue;
    }
}
```